# Amplitude of periodic function

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

I want to find the amplitude of a periodic function. The function happens to be a sum of different sawtooth functions each with amplitude 1 but different periods.  (The period of the sum function is just the lowest common multiple of the components.)

Now, if the function was a sum of continuous functions, I gather we could differentiate the function and the maxima and minima would occur where the derivative equals zero.  However, sawtooth functions are discontinuous and can't be differentiated at the points of discontinuity.  In a sum of sawtooth functions, the maxima and minima occur at points of discontinuity.  So, is there another way to determine the amplitude of the sum function?

Eg. consider 3 sawtooth functions $f(A), f(B), f(C)$ each having amplitude 1, and period $1$, $2$ and $3$ respectively.  The sum function is, say, $f(X) = f(A) + f(B) - f(C)$.  The $f(A)$ component with period $1$ results in points of discontinuity at every integer value.

In this particular simple example, the period of the sum function is $6$, and the amplitude is approximately $2.2$, with a maximum of approximately $1.1$ at $x=4$ and minimum of approximately $-1.1$ at $x=2$.  However, in the sum function there are local maxima and minima, with points of discontinuity, at every integer value.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: There are continuous functions that are not differentiable anywhere, so continuity is not enough to allow taking a derivative. If you have a function that is differentiable except at isolated points, the maxima and minima will occur at places where either the derivative is $0$ or it does not exist. So if you identify all those points for your sum function, you can evaluate them to find the maxima and minima.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately a sum of sawtooth functions has points of discontinuity everywhere.  See example added to question.

Comment: Six points of discontinuity is far from "everywhere". In fact it is almost trivial, When you have to evaluate 20 or 30 points, or even a few hundred, then you can start to complain about how much work it is.

Comment: Yes, it is obviously a deliberately trivial example.  If the periods of the 3 constituent functions are $2$, $97$ and $5077$ instead, the period of the sum function is $7,117,954$ with millions of points of discontinuity per period.  Now imagine 100 component functions.  How to find the maxima/minima other than brute force?